# How to permanently set environment variable?

Tags: ansible

Host is Ubuntu 16.04

I'm trying to set environment variable for user, with:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: user1
  tasks:
  - name: Adding the path in the bashrc files
    lineinfile: dest=/home/user1/.bashrc line='export MY_VAR=TEST' insertafter='EOF' state=present

  - name: Source the bashrc file
    shell: . /home/user1/.bashrc 

  - debug: msg={{lookup('env','MY_VAR')}}
```

Unfortunately it outputs:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [xxxxx.xxx] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

How can I export variable so next time I run some tasks on this machine I can use `{{ lookup('env', 'MY_VAR') }}` to get value of this variable?

Answer (score 9):

Because lookups happen locally, and because each task runs in it's own process, you need to do something a bit different.

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: user1
  tasks:
  - name: Adding the path in the bashrc files
    lineinfile: dest=/home/user1/.bashrc line='export MY_VAR=TEST' insertafter='EOF' state=present

  - shell: . /home/user1/.bashrc && echo $MY_VAR
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
    register: myvar

  - debug: var=myvar.stdout
```

In this example I am sourcing the .bashrc and checking the var in the same command, and storing the value with `register`

Answer (score 1):

All lookups in Ansible are local. See [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html) for details:

> **Note**
>   Lookups occur on the local computer, not on the remote computer.